# Use of TreeMap <Double, List<String>>

Tags: android, sorting, hashmap, expandablelistview, treemap

I want to sorted value which is based on key So I used TreeMap which is given sorted key but I want to sorted key as well as value also according to key.
Here key as Double and value as Array-list.

`MainActivity.java`

```
public void getExpandableListData() {
        Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getLoadMoreData(count);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String businessName;
        String latitude;
        String longitude;
        String categoryDescription;
        double difference;
        do {
            TreeMap<Double, List<ChildInfo>> treeMapLocationDifference;
            treeMapLocationDifference = new TreeMap<Double, List<ChildInfo>>();
            categoryDescription = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("categorydesc"));
            int categoryId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("CategoryId"));
            listDataHeader.add(categoryDescription);
            List<ChildInfo> childList = new ArrayList<ChildInfo>();
            Cursor cursorChild = databaseHelper.getChildData(categoryId);
            Map.Entry<Double, List<ChildInfo>> entry;
            List<ChildInfo> list = null;
            cursorChild.moveToFirst();
            do {
                businessName = cursorChild.getString(cursorChild
                        .getColumnIndex("BusinessName"));
                phoneNumber = cursorChild.getString(cursorChild
                        .getColumnIndex("Phone"));
                categoryDescription = cursorChild.getString(cursorChild
                        .getColumnIndex("categorydesc"));
                latitude = cursorChild.getString(cursorChild
                .getColumnIndex("Latitude"));
                longitude = cursorChild.getString(cursorChild
                        .getColumnIndex("Longitude"));
                ChildInfo childInfo = new ChildInfo(businessName, phoneNumber,
                        categoryDescription, latitude, longitude);
                childList.add(childInfo);
                currentLocation = new Location("");
                currentLocation.setLatitude(18.5522);
                currentLocation.setLongitude(73.8956);
                Location savedLocation = new Location("databaseLocation");
                savedLocation.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(latitude));
                savedLocation.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(longitude));
                difference = currentLocation.distanceTo(savedLocation) * (0.001);
                treeMapLocationDifference.put(difference, childList);
                entry = treeMapLocationDifference.entrySet().iterator().next();
                list = new ArrayList<ChildInfo>();
                list = entry.getValue();
                listDataChild.put(categoryDescription, list);
            } while (cursorChild.moveToNext());
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
    }
```

Here I used Tree-map and I want to this tree-map sorted by key as well as his corresponding value also then I will assign this value to value of hash-map which should be sorted.

Comment: Can you pleas write simple examples: what you got, and what you want to get?

Comment: Example  
Keys : 1.84, 2.35, 5.89, 0.21
values: {Burger, 02058795247}, {Pizza, 02087958742}, {Rolls, 020547896874}, {Sandwich, 02058967412}  

Result should be
keys : 0.21, 1.84, 2.35, 5.89
Values: {Sandwich, 02058967412}, {Burger, 02058795247}, {Pizza, 02087958742}, {Rolls, 020547896874}

But I got result like
keys : 0.21, 1.84, 2.35, 5.89
values: {Burger, 02058795247}, {Pizza, 02087958742}, {Rolls, 020547896874}, {Sandwich, 02058967412} @AterLux

Comment: Because you are the same list to arr values in treeMapLocationDifference. Everyone is assigned to childList, but childList is created only once, before the loop. What you trying to do in bottom four lines of the loop - is out of explanation.

Comment: Actually I want to set data to expandable list-view & this method call from oncreate method @AterLux